# PHP database insert issue

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

This is my code

```
    <?php
$host="localhost";
$user="root";
$pass="admin";
$dbname="news";
$connection=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$dbname);
if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    die("Database Connection Failed >> Error Name : " . mysqli_error() . " Error number : " . mysqli_connect_errno());
}
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.thenews.com.pk/NewsSubIndex.aspx?ID=5'); //get the html returned from the following url

$pokemon_doc = new DOMDocument();

libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);
  $pokemon_doc->loadHTML($html);
  libxml_clear_errors(); 

  $pokemon_xpath = new DOMXPath($pokemon_doc);

    $pokemon_row = $pokemon_xpath->query('//table[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_DataListSubIndex"]/tr');
    foreach($pokemon_row as $row){
          $headline= $row->nodeValue;
          echo $headline;
          $mysqli_query="INSERT INTO `thenews_entertainment` (`news`) VALUES ('".$headline."')";
          echo $mysqli_query;
          $result=mysqli_query($connection,$mysqli_query);
          echo $result;
          mysqli_close($connection);
          break;
          }

?>
```

I am not able to insert the record in database.But i have echo the query and the copied that query from browser and executed on mysql console and it inserts the record successfully.Why it is not inserting from my Code.

Comment: You don't check `$mysqli_error()` which will tell you what's wrong. You also don't properly escape your values.

Comment: You're simply asssuming it succeeded. Try `mysqli_query($connection, $mysqli_query) or die(mysqli_error($connection))`

Comment: but you can check i have echoed the query and it executed on mysql console

Comment: Echoing the query just shows you what the query string is, not the result from the query. Check mysqli_error(), these functions exist for a reason

Comment: echo $result;  is displaying 1 which shows it has inserted the row but it does not appears in table but the id record is generated

Answer (score 1):

There are two essential flaws can be seen in your code.

1. Lack of **prepared statements** use
2. Lack of error reporting.

These two things you have to have **unconditionally**, despite of what you think of the matter.

However, mysqli too troublesome with first issue. So, I'd suggest to use PDO instead. In the [PDO tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info) you will find tutorials for both.

Rewrite your code to follow both these obligatory rules and you will have either data inserted or an error message which will tell you what's going wrong.

Comment: As to #2, enabling exceptions with [`mysqli_report`](http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-driver.report-mode.php) might be a good idea. Errors are a lot harder to ignore that way.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe escaping your variable $headline wouldn't be a bad idea:
use this: [https://www.php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string][1]
[1]: https://www.php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string "mysqli_real_escape_string"

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Sorry but this wasn't his question.